# Update data using search & replaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, grep, cut

```
get_data.txt
ald900  NON-Prod        GOOG037-A   US
ald9024 NON-Prod        GOOG037-A   SRI-LANKA
ald978  NON-Prod        GOOG037-A   JAPAN
```

I have two given data. I need to search in get_data.txt needs to update in resultant.txt. I can able to grep data from get_data.txt but not able update in resultant.txt.

```
resultant.txt
ald900.google.com   #N/A    #N/A
ald978.vci.google.com   #N/A    0
ald9024.google.com  #N/A    #N/A
```

Sample code

```
while read ln
  do
  cat get_data.txt |grep $ln |awk '{print $4}'
done < cat resultant.txt | cut -d "." -f1
```

By this i can get value to update but how to update result of "cat get_data.txt |grep $ln |awk '{print $4}'" with #N/A & 0 in resultant.txt

Needs result like

```
resultant.txt
ald900.google.com   #N/A    US
ald978.vci.google.com   #N/A    JAPAN
ald9024.google.com  #N/A    SRI-LANKA
```

Answer (score 3):

Go for awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$NF;next}{split($1,arr,/\./);$NF=a[arr[1]]}1' get_data.txt resultant.txt > tmpfile
mv tmpfile resultant.txt
```

Output:

```
ald900.google.com #N/A US
ald978.vci.google.com #N/A JAPAN
ald9024.google.com #N/A SRI-LANKA
```

What awk is doing?

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{
        a[$1]=$NF           #Array `a` stores last fields of get_data.txt using the 1st fields as keys
        next
    } 
    {
        split($1,arr,/\./)  #Split 1st field of resultant.txt on the dots
        $NF=a[arr[1]]       #Retrieve the corresponding element in a and replace the last field with it
    }
    1                       #Print the resulting line
' get_data.txt resultant.txt
```

Note: If you want output file to be tab separated, add `-v OFS='\t'` to awk (`awk -v OFS='\t' '...' get_data.txt resultant.txt > tmpfile`).